# Violent sci-fi comic 90s/00s (might be French) with warrior types on a desert planet

Tags: story-identification, comics, aliens, bandes-dessinees

I'm looking for a comic which I read at the end of the 1990s, maybe early 2000s. It was a rather recent comic back then. I grew up in Belgium, so not sure if it was in English or French (or translated Dutch). Some things I remember:

- It was located on another planet with Dune-like / Mojave desert landscapes. I recall the colours being all shades of orange and brown.
- There were several men introduced, between six and eight I guess, maybe more. I think most of them were bare-chested and warrior-like, wearing cloths and leather. They all had specific skills and formed a kind of pack. You'd guess they were introduced for further development later in the comic, but...
- They were hunting blackish alien- / insect-like creatures who slaughtered most of them. The graphics were extremely violent, gore and bloody. It also felt a bit like the start of the first Azumi film, were some of the characters you grew to love in this very short period of time, were already killed off.
- Graphic-wise it resembled Jodorowsky & Gimenez' The Metabarons and Lawrence & Lodewijk's Storm, but I'm sure it's none of those two series.

I've been trying to find this comic for many, many years now. Although I realise I'm not giving a lot of information, I hope it's already something.

Comment: [Terra Formars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_Formars) matches some plot points, but it's a manga and it's decidedly more recent (2011 - present).